# Deployment in Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I'm new in symfony2 , I want to deploy my application but when i launch the command :

```
git push heroku master
```

i obtain the following error message :  [InvalidArgumentException]  The parameter handler needs to be configured through the extra.incenteev-parameters setting.

Comment: Have you already used your favourite search engine on "parameter handler" and "extra.incenteev-parameters"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with [Incenteev's Parameter Handler](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler). Have you followed the instructions in the README? Specifically adding this

```
{
    "require": {
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
            }
    }
}
```

It seems you have not added the last part in the json and the parameters YAML file too. Adding that should solve the problem

Comment: Unfortunately ! I tried it but i have always the same error message : [InvalidArgumentException] The parameter handler needs to be configured through the extra.incenteev-parameters setting.